# Little problems from a Haskell learner about filter & fold

Tags: haskell

This is my second day learning Haskell and I am stuck terribly by a problem.
I tried to solve the eighth problem in [99 Haskell questions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10)
The problem is to write a function called "compress" which works like this:

```
>compress "aaaabbbbccccddddd"
"abcd"
>compress [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

and here's what I wrote:

```
compress :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
compress [] = []
compress x = filter ( (head x) `notElem` ( compress $ tail x ) ) x
```

The compiler said:

> Couldn't match expected type `a -> Bool' with actual type` Bool'

In `compress`, I tried to recursively pick up new elements from end to head. (like backtracking maybe??)

Is my algorithm wrong?
Is there alternative way to implement the algorithm in a more readable way?
(Like: where to put parentheses? or `$` )

Can someone kindly help me with it?
Thanks a lot.

---

Thanks to Lubomir's help, I corrected my code by :

> compress'(x:xs) = x : compress' (dropWhile (== x) xs)

and it works!

And thanks everyone, I feel spoiled!  **You guys are so kind!**

I'll keep on learning Haskell!

Comment: always recompile after modifications before posting here. you have a typo

Comment: It's refreshing to find a beginner having a good go before asking here. Keep working hard and you'll learn a lot.

Comment: This is my first post at Stackoverflow.  It's amazing that everybody help me so generously!!  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm is basically fine, but it does not typecheck. The first argument to `filter` should be a function of type `a -> Bool` – for an element of the list it should tell you whether or not to throw it out. What you have is a single `Bool` value.

The second part of the function may be better implemented with a different pattern. This would allow you to drop the `head` and `tail` functions.

```
compress [] = []
compress (x:xs) = x : compress (filter (/= x) xs)
```

This pattern binds `x` to the first element of the list and `xs` is the tail of the list. The function should include `x` in the result and recursively call itself on filtered `xs` (with `x` removed from it).

EDIT: this function does not do what the problem requests. Only consecutive duplicates should be eliminated. This can be fixed by using `dropWhile` instead of `filter` and slightly modifying the predicate function.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there alternative way to implement the algorithm in a more readable
>   way?

Yes.

```
import Data.List

compress :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
compress = map head . group
```

`map head . group` is basically `\xs -> map head (group xs)`. `group xs` will create a list of lists were all equal consecutive elements are grouped together in a list. `map head` will then take the `head`s of these lists discarding the rest as required.

Comment: may be worth tacking on a `sort` so as to handle cases where the input list is unsorted: `compress = map head . group . sort` (type stays the same, `sort` is in `Data.List`)   EDIT: just saw that the exercise just wants us to eliminate consecutive duplicates only (i.e., not all duplicates).  so ignore this... (i don't see a delete button...)

Answer (score 2):

Check the signature of filter:

```
Prelude> :t filter
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Note that the first argument must be a function. Now check the type of your expression within the paranthesis.

```
Prelude> :t notElem
notElem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

Thus, `notElem a b` will return a value of type `Bool`.

Note: I think you might have misunderstood the problem statement. What is the expected output for `aaabbbaaa`?
I would argue it should be `aba`, as the problem is stated as

> Eliminate **consecutive** duplicates of list elements.

(emphasize mine).

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. The example given is `compress "aaaabccaadeeee"` returning `"abcade"`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did misunderstand in the first place.